# Сохранение файла в C#

Tags: c#

Написал такой метод, вроде один в один как на оф. документации, а не работает :(

```
public void SaveFile()
        {
            SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
            if(saveFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                if((saveFileDialog.OpenFile()) != null)
                 {
                    richTextBox1.SaveFile(saveFileDialog.FileName);
                 }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 4):

Вот так:

```
SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
if (saveFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
   richTextBox1.SaveFile(saveFileDialog.OpenFile(), RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText);
}
```

Вы когда в условии проверяете

```
if((saveFileDialog.OpenFile()) != null)
```

он уже его открывает на запись. А потом метод

```
richTextBox1.SaveFile(saveFileDialog.FileName);
```

снова пытается открыть тот же файл на запись, и поэтому выскакивает исключение, что файл уже занят.
А можно просто отдать имя файла методу SaveFile:

```
SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
if (saveFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
   richTextBox1.SaveFile(saveFileDialog.FileName);
}
```

Comment: А как сделать, чтобы имя файла было у меня в title окна программы?

Comment: Код:

    this.Text = saveFileDialog.FileName.Substring(saveFileDialog.FileName.LastIndexOf('\\\\') + 1);

Comment: а когда открываю файл пустой или не пустой вылазит 

{\rtf1\ansi\deff0{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset204 Microsoft Sans Serif;}}
\viewkind4\uc1\pard\lang1049\f0\fs17\par
}

как убрать?

Comment: Не понял вопроса.

Comment: @Данил, я когда файл сохраняю пустой, он создается, все норм, но внутри его не понятный текст появляется

Comment: Он его в rtf-формате сохраняет. Так что надо полагать это игнформация о файле

Comment: Как это исправить?

Comment: Вы его сохраняйте с разширением rtf и открывай офисом. А если надо чтобы он открывался просто блокнотом, то смысл использовать richtextbox нет.